# std::chrono add days to current date

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I would like to use std::chrono in order to find calculate the date in the future based on an expiration period.

The expiration period is an integer that specifies "days from now". So how do I use chrono lib in order to find the date after 100 days?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you have a [`time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). To add days to that object you can just use `operator+` with `std::chrono::hours` :

```
#include <chrono>
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point t = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::system_clock::time_point new_t = t + std::chrono::hours(100 * 24);
```

Comment: One could also `using namespace std::litterals` and then, write `new_t = t + (100 * 24h)`, just for style

Comment: OK, great, can I convert the time_point to epoch? I want to store that moment in a database in a format that will be portable from other services

Comment: @DragonRock it's too late to edit your comment now but the correct spelling is `std::literals` and it is C++14

Comment: You can be more selective, with `using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals` if you don't want the whole `std::literals` in scope.

Answer (score 9):

Howard Hinnant's [date library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html) is free (open-source); it extends `<chrono>` with calendrical services:

```
#include "date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto now = system_clock::now();
    auto today = floor<days>(now);
    year_month_day future = today + days{100};
    std::cout << future << '\n';
}
```

The above program gets the current time with `system_clock::now()`, and then truncates that `time_point` to have a precision of `days`.  Then `100 days` are added to find the future `time_point` which is then converted into a `{year, month, day}` structure for human consumption.

The output is currently:

```
2017-05-19
```

If you want to do this type of computation without the benefit of a 3rd-party library, I highly recommend creating a `chrono::duration days` like so:

```
using days = std::chrono::duration
    <int, std::ratio_multiply<std::ratio<24>, std::chrono::hours::period>>;
```

Now you can add `days{100}` to a `system_clock::time_point`.

Comment: Looks great, I will follow up.

Comment: Any plans you will include the extensions in std's `<chrono>` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki:  Working on it: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0355r1.html  Chance of success is 50/50.

Comment: @HowardHinnant 50%? I don't see any competing proposals, this one does all I'd ever want, so why would anyone in his right mind oppose this? Chrono TS at the very least should be a no-brainer.

Comment: @TemplateRex:  Competing proposal is this pair of papers:  open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0215r0.html and open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0216r0.html .  Also this is an extremely controversial topic on the committee.  Put 20 committee members in a room and you'll get 25 different opinions on the right way to handle this topic.  As I write this the server for those links is down, but hopefully that's temporary.

Answer (score 1):

The chrono library contains no calendar functionality. There is no direct way to accurately achieve what you are asking for.

You can find a timestamp that is 100 days worth of seconds in future by using a duration with ratio of seconds per day. But chrono has no tools for calculating the date.