# How do I convert the number of Julian days into the Julian date? 44332 into May 17 2021?

Tags: c++

I am able to convert a regular date such as 05/19/2021 into Julian date number 44334 (the amount of days passed since year 1990).

However, I am required to now do the opposite, and I just have no idea how.

Could you please help me out on logic here?

Comment: You just invert your calculation. Not even a programming problem, just solving an equation for a different variable. High-school stuff.

Comment: Since you already have the code to convert `05/19/2021` to `44334`, you can just reorganize your code structure to have an intermediate representation of the date, then do the opposite would be easy.

Comment: See [github example](https://github.com/JohannesBuchner/libnova/blob/master/src/julian_day.c) and many other examples to draw from.

Comment: There's a terminology issue here.  The Julian day number is a count of days since November 24, 4714 BC, in the proleptic Gregorian calendar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).  A Julian date is a date in the Julian calendar (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_calendar).  05/19/2021 is only 11461 days after 01/01/1990.  What you're looking for is the number of days after 1899-12-31.  This is often referred to as an Excel date as it was the measure used in Microsoft Excel.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `date.h` or its C++20 implementation in case you already use it.

```
using namespace date;
using namespace date::literals;
```

This will do the trick.

```
year_month_day ymd(1990_y/01/01); // Create a date object. '_y' is a literal like 'f' for float which comes with `date::literals` or `chorno::literals`.
sys_days total_days = (sys_days)ymd; // Convert it to a time_point.
total_days += days(44334); // Add the days.
year_month_day later = total_days; // Convert it back to an object.
```

I found help here:
[std::chrono add days to current date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42114518/stdchrono-add-days-to-current-date)

Comment: @Codeissimple What is still missing?